# Support for em.merge / em.refresh in Panache

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, quarkus

I wanted to implement something like this with Panache in Quarkus

```
open fun add(person: Person) {
    em.persist(person)
    em.flush()
    em.refresh(person)
}
```

So that i can access the inserted id from the Person.

I now want to use a `PersonDao` which derives from `PanacheRepository<Person>`.
The only way of achieving the same effect as above that I see is:

```
open fun add(person: Person) {
    personDao.persistAndFlush(person)
    Panache.getEntityManager().refresh(person)
}
```

The call to `Panache.getEntityManager()` seems kind of inelegant to me. Is there a better way? And what's with `Panache.getEntityManager().merge(person)`?

Edit: I now know that `persistAndFlush` populates the id. But what would I do, if I also needed all of the other fields?

Comment: I think that on your example `Panache.getEntityManager().refresh(person)` is not needed as the changes of the database is reflected on the person object when you call `persistAndFlush` (the id field is populated)

Comment: Ah yes, that's indeed true, thanks! That solves my problem, but I am curious how one would solve a case, where he also wants all the other properties to be refreshed.

Comment: No flush is needed. Immediately after _persist_ you will have the ID assigned.

Comment: @Sanne Thank you for your response. I guess it makes sense, the flush was there as a  artifact from the refresh.